# Disable clickonce application rollback

Tags: deployment, clickonce

is there any way for disabling the rollback (getting the previous version) in an clickonce installed application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your project's properties, switch to the `Publish` tab and click the `Updates` button. The dialog that pops up has a section for a "minimum required version for this application", which lets you enforce that a user upgrade to a specific version.

Once you've set that, users shouldn't be able to roll back to a previous version. They'll also be forced to upgrade if they're running a version older than the minimum.

Note that I haven't tried this, but it's my understanding of the "minimum version" feature.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that making the minimum required version equal to the current version does, in fact, work.